# How can I filter on GA requests which contain "X-Purpose:preview" on the header?

Tags: filter, google-analytics, httprequest, prefetch

Good morning and thanks in advance. My GA is going crazy because we are getting traffic from a source that "preloads" our pages for their users. This means that although not all of their users end up in our site, GA still counts each "prefetch" as a session of 1-2 seconds. I need to filter HTTP requests that contain "X-Purpose:preview" at the header but the current regular expression I am ussing is not working. As of now I put: Exclude Request URI and then this regex:

(X-Purpose:preview)

it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone out there is trying to solve this... I posted it on GA forum and seems there is no way to make this work. If anyone can think of a way to make it work I'd be immensely grateful: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Filters/How-can-I-filter-on-GA-requests-which-contain-X-Purpose-preview/m-p/1252519#